# Can't build Firebird SQL on Oracle Linux 8 Ampere V1 (arm64)

Tags: c++, firebird

I'm not, by any means, a C++ expert and Linux neither. I just want to take the oracle free tier a spin.
4 CPU's with 24gb seems too good for personal projects.

I'm trying to build v4.0.2 from source but I'm stuck with this message:

```
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/opc/firebird/gen'
g++ -static-libstdc++ -pthread -Wl,-rpath,/lib -Wl,-rpath,/intl -Wl,--version-script,empty.vers
/home/opc/firebird/temp/Release/gpre/c_cxx.o
...
/home/opc/firebird/temp/Release/common.a -o 
/home/opc/firebird/gen/Release/firebird/bin/gpre_boot -L/home/opc/firebird/gen/Release/firebird/lib -latomic -lm -ldl -ldecFloat -lre2

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

After the machine was created (Linux Oracle 8, a branch of CentOS 8) I've run the following commands:

```
git clone -b v4.0.2 https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird.git
sudo yum group install "Development Install"
sudo yum install llvm-toolset libicu libicu-devel ncurses ncurses-devel
./autogen.sh --with-system-editline=yes --with-system-icu
./configure --with-builtin-tommath --with-builtin-tomcrypt --prefix=/opt/firebird
Make
```

It seems something with static libraries, which I've tried to find without any luck.

Any help?

As this question was marked as duplicate, i just want to add that none of those answers in 13195110 doesnt work. All development packages was installed, there arent static devel packages to install. I suspect that has something to do with ARM build.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ld%3A+cannot+find+-lstdc%2B

Comment: If you run into other problems building Firebird, I suggest to ask on the [firebird-devel Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-devel)

Comment: i post that exact question on firebird git page, without any luck yet. thanks